# Phaser 3, Physics Editor and Matter JS: problem changing shapes

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework, matter.js

I'm currently working on a Phaser 3 game project. I am currently using MatterJS Physics. In order to setup the body physics I used Physics Editor (https://www.codeandweb.com/physicseditor).

Now I wanted to change the physics body shape accordingly with the frame I am currently on.

So far I was able to change the body shape using `this.setBody(this.shapes[str], {});`, whereas this.shapes is previously declared as `this.shapes = scene.cache.json.get('heroPhysics');`, beeing `'heroPhysics'` the Physics JSON file generated by Physics Editor.

However, when I change the body shape the body goes to position (0,0). I also wanted to flip the physics body(the actual sprite I'm able to) but I can't.

How can I perform that?

Thank you!!

Comment: Maybe it's because you have declared `'heroPhysics'` at the `(0, 0, ...)` when you added it to the game, you can try to debug your game to have some informations about it displayed on the screen while you're developping it or with `console.log(...)`